# Get cursor position in all buffers

Tags: vimscript, buffers

The `line(".")`, command gets the line in the current buffer. Whats the command to get line in an arbitrary buffer, using buffer numbers?

Comment: `:h getbufline()`

Answer (score 2):

The `getbufinfo()` returns a list of dictionaries. One of the dictionary key is `lnum` - line number. One other key is `bufn` - buffer number.

Comment: Note this function is a rather recent addition to vim's libraries (post 7.4.2204, Aug 2016)